# Take Picture when Face Detected android-vision API

Tags: android, android-camera2, google-vision

I've already checked out [Take photo when face detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431169/take-photo-when-face-detected). However that uses `FaceDetectionListener` which is deprecated.

I have a **FaceTracker** which tracks faces and draws a box around that face. This is the code from google samples- https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker

I also have an app **Camera2Basic** that takes pictures when a button is pressed. This code uses Camera2API which is what Google recommends. Here's the code- https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

What I need to do is take a picture automatically whenever a face is detected as opposed to when I press a button, which is what Camera2Basic does. 
`FaceTracker` has an `Activity`- `FaceTrackerActivity`, which has a method

```
        /**
         * Start tracking the detected face instance within the face overlay.
         */
        @Override
        public void onNewItem(int faceId, Face item) {
            mFaceGraphic.setId(faceId);
        }
```

And `Camera2Basic` has a `Fragment` - `Camera2BasicFragment` which has a method `onClick` (representing the `onClickListener` for the Picture `Button`). `onClick()` calls a method `takePicture()` which is what I need to get automatically called whenever `onNewItem` in `FaceTracker` is detected.

Here's `onClick`-

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.picture: {
                takePicture();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.info: {
                Activity activity = getActivity();
                if (null != activity) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                            .setMessage(R.string.intro_message)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                            .show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

And here's `takePicture`-

```
    /**
     * Initiate a still image capture.
     */
    private void takePicture() {
        lockFocus();
}
```

However, I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to do that because both apps are structured differently, and my attempts at combining the two haven't really worked well so far.

Comment: there might be textureview or surfaceview for both to open camera and show preview inside it. then use that surface to capture at any condition you want.

Comment: I know it's and old post, but I based in same circumstances on the face tracking example. Then you can run method `takePicture()` on `cameraSource` object, which requires you to set callback on taking a picture